# start an activity from a fragment (app is not starting)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, onclicklistener

im still new to Kotlin... i have a drawer, which changes between fragments.

in the home fragment i want to have a button, which starts an activity. my fragment class looks like this:

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class Home : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener {
            /* Start Activity */
            val i = Intent(activity, strooptest::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment Home.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Home().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

my app won't start and I'm not sure what im doing wrong here. Also im not having any Errors or Exceptions!

Comment: that code to start an activity looks correct. What do you mean "my app won't start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all of your code for the `HomeFragment` then it seems like you are missing a declaration of `imageButton1`?

I would recommend reading into how to create a fragment to get a better understanding. Annoyingly the official Android documentation for creating a fragment seems lacking but [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments) seems to have a nice code example, especially referring to `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated`.

Comment: now i know where my mistake was. i was missing the onViewCreated method.
 now i after i implemented the listener in the onViewCreated its working correctly. Thanx.